# GoogleStrategy is not fired when Google callback

Tags: node.js, passport.js

The example suggests the following:

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Which is working fine but I registered a route and method for the route is as follow and it's not working.

```
exports.googleCallback = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    (function(req, res) {
      // Successful authentication, redirect home.
      res.redirect('/');
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

It directly redirects and not called the following:

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log('Log here');
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }

));
```

I have the `console.log` method which never prints in call back but directly redirecting the page to `/`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you rewrote your code so you can use something like this:

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback', googleCallback)
```

In that case, you can use the fact that *arrays* of middleware are also supported by Express:

```
exports.googleCallback = [
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  })
]
```

Your code is the equivalent of this:

```
exports.googleCallback = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' });

  const handler = function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  };

 handler(req, res, next);
};
```

Which does something completely different (but explains why only the redirect happens).